# How do you iterate through dynamically created objects?

Tags: java, android, object, checkbox

Lets say you have an object like this and you want to have the program go through each dynamically created Checkbox to see if it has not been checked.

If has not been checked, then the program should create a notification alerting the user that one or more of these objects has not been checked.

What is the best way to have the program identify whether the checkbox is checked or not?

Each time I run the program, it only applies to the last created Checkbox regardless of how many checked or unchecked checkboxes proceed it.
Thank you for your time.

```
View ObjectView;
CheckBox check;
 //A whole bunch of code here.   
public void onClick(View arg0) {


                if (check==null){

                }

                else if (check==null || check.isChecked()){

                }

                else {

                    ObjectView.getId();
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
                        .setContentTitle("Items missing")
                        .setContentText("One or more items are missing");
                int ID_Notify = 01;
                getActivity();

                NotificationManager managenote = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                managenote.notify(ID_Notify, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: are you creating checkboxes dynamically?

Comment: Try to put your all check box inside one parent layout and try to iterate through parent layout child count and get child at position check value of child.

Comment: Yes. All of the checkboxes are being created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Im gonna help you with an example of my code and try to explain it, aware that im **not** gonna babysit you (means you cant just copy paste) because i still have some work to do.

First, a new dynamic `spinner` will be created everytime you click a button (inside `onClick`) :

```
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinChildAdapter);
        parentSpinner.addView(spinner);
        spinner.setId(totalDynamicChild); //the spinner's id will be the increment from 0
        spinnderIdList.add(totalDynamicChild); //list of the dynamic spinner ID
        totalDynamicChild++;
```

Then, we can access those dynamic Spinners with :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < totalDynamicChild; i++)
    {
        Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(spinnderIdList.get(i));
        //do something with the spinner's object here
    }
```

Feel free to comment if you have some questions.